# decimal.TryParse and decimal variable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a value of `4128.27797873696027992918696321` as `string` coming back from a service. The goal is to assign the result to a `decimal` variable `Foo`. So I tried the following:

Parse the string to `decimal` by doing :

```
    var returnValue = value?.Length < 28 ? value : value?.Substring(0, 28);
    decimal.TryParse(returnValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var parsed);
```

While I do get the value on `parsed` variable, however, when I attempt to set the result to `Foo` by doing `Foo = parsed` the value of `Foo` is `0`. Can't get my head around it why is `Foo` `0`?

PS: `NumberStyles.Float` needs to stay same for `decimal.TryParse`

Comment: What *is* Foo? Can show the declaration of it?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to assign the value to ```Foo```?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - `decimal.TryParse` works fine with "4128.27797873696027992918696321" for me.

Comment: Apologies as it seems I have a constraint on `Setter` which was disallowing it. Thanks everyone. And Thanks specially to @JonSkeet sir!

Comment: Vote and close this please